# Is there a way to increase the chance of catching shinies on Black and White 2?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

I am trying to collect shiny Pokemon, but my luck has been down in the dumps. I don't want to resort to using my action replay, are there any ways that are proven to increase the chance to find or hatch a shiny Pokemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of methods available to increase your likelihood of encountering a shiny pokemon.

> Capture All National Pokédex
>
> **Method**: Finally, when you manage to capture all the Pokémon in the
>   National Pokédex (not counting event legends) and show it to Cedric
>   Juniper, he will tell you his daughter has a present for you.
>
> This present is the special Shiny Charm. This item increases the likelihood
>   that you will encounter Shiny Pokémon. When you have the item in your
>   bag, then the chances of encountering Shiny Pokémon in the wild is
>   increased to 33% of normal, making it a 1 in 2,370.6 chance. If,
>   however, you\'re using the Masuda Method to breed, it increases it
>   from 1 in 1,365.3 down to 1 in 1024.

Source: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/dexcompletion.shtml)

The [Masuda method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method) mentioned above can also be used without the Shiny Charm:

> Rather than encountering Shiny Pokémon with a probability of 1/8192,
>   the Masuda method lets players breed Pokémon of differing real-world
>   geographical origin with a 5/8192 (Generation IV) or 3/4096
>   (Generation V) probability of being Shiny upon hatching.